# Incorrectly positioned UITableViewCell when containing UITextField

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I've created a simple project. It contains a `UITableViewController` with self-sizing prototype cells that contain a `UITextField` and a `UILabel` for displaying validation message. The controls are grouped in a `UIStackView`, but that doesn't seem to matter.

The label is only visible if there is a message to display, otherwise it's size collapses to 0. To adjust the size of the cell I simple call the recommended:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

If I scroll the view with the `UITextfield` remaining first responder (ie w/o dismissing the keyboard), so that the cell is no longer visible, when scrolling back to the cell, it is misaligned.

I've hosted the sample project at https://github.com/ionel71089/tableViewTextField

[image: simulator snapshot]

**Note:**
Easiest way to reproduce is on Simulator iPhone 6 9.2, by editing let's say the 50th cell, scrolling to the top and then back to the cell.

Comment: Can't reproduce this error. Use Simulator, iPhone 5s, 9.3. Maybe use tableview.reload()?
I have never see tableView.beginUpdates in this combination. Have a look here: http://www.matrixprojects.net/p/uitableview-moves-and-updates/